# jest assert a function have been called twice and both times with particular argument

Tags: jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am testing a Vue component that dispatches an action(`functionx`) on mount. The same action(`functionx`) is dispatched when a particular `refresh` button is clicked. I am testing the behavior of that refresh button - that is the vuex dispatch action is called with argument 'functionx'. Here is my test:

```js
   it('makes an api call to server when refresh button is clicked', () => {
      store.dispatch = jest.fn();

      const wrapper = mount(Categories, {
         sync: false,
         store,
         localVue
      });

      const refreshButton = wrapper.find('span.fa-sync');
      refreshButton.trigger('click');

      expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('categoryStore/fetchCategories');
   })
});
```

which passes. Now since the same action is dispatched initially when the component is mounted. So in total dispatch is called twice. I know I can use `.toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(nthCall, arg1, arg2, ....)` to check that dispatch was called both times with same argument, but for that I will have to write two expect statements, like below:

```js
expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 'categoryStore/fetchCategories');
expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, 'categoryStore/fetchCategories');
```

Is there any way I can achieve the above thing in one statement? Any matcher function or any property on the `expect` object that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there's currently no easy matcher for this situation ([list of matchers](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect)).

You could do it "manually" using the `.mock` parameter, something like this:

```js
function assertFunctionWasCalledTimesWith(jestFunction, times, argument) {
    expect(jestFunction.mock.calls.filter((call) => call[0] === argument).length)
        .toBe(times)
}
```

(Using the `filter` method makes the `times` assertion only take into account the calls that have given `argument`)

Using the above function you could assert your code like this:

```js
assertFunctionWasCalledTimesWith(store.dispatch, 2, 'categoryStore/fetchCategories')
```

Of course, the message when the test fails won't be very descriptive, but it works, anyway.